# why android studio app only run in android version 11 and they don't run another mobile version

Tags: java, android, firebase, video, jitsi

> ```
>      @Override
>         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>             setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
>     
>             auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
>     
>             dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
>             dialog.setMessage("Please Wait.... ");
>     
>            email  = findViewById(R.id.email);
>     
>             password = findViewById(R.id.password);
>     
>             loginenter = findViewById(R.id.loginenter);
>             loginenter.setOnClickListener(this);
>     
>             register = findViewById(R.id.register);
>     
>             forgetpassword = findViewById(R.id.forgetpassword);
>     
>             register.setOnClickListener(this);
>     
>             forgetpassword.setOnClickListener(this);
>     
>         }
>     
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             dialog.show();
>             switch (v.getId()){
>                 case R.id.register:
>                     startActivity(new Intent(this, SignupActivity.class));
>                     break;
>
>   
>
> > //Error[Error on android version][1]
>
>     03/22 12:04:08: Launching 'app' on OPPO CPH1923.
>     Install successfully finished in 14 s 86 ms.
>     $ adb shell am start -n "com.example.together/com.example.together.MainActivity" -a
> ```
>
> android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
> Connected to process 23620 on device 'oppo-cph1923-CQI7GYHUFI9HAENR'.
> Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the
> "Debugger" settings page.
> V/ColorAnimationUtils: ColorAnimationUtils this =:com.color.util.ColorAnimationUtils@a915b45
> V/ColorAnimationUtils:  initData  mEnableAnimation =: false
> mData =:null,data =: com.color.util.ColorAnimationData@611129a,this
> =:com.color.util.ColorAnimationUtils@a915b45
> I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
> I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
> W/xample.togethe: create CommonDcsHelper
> W/xample.togethe: cacheJniMembers success
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/os/Trace;->TRACE_TAG_APP:J (light greylist, reflection)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->isTagEnabled(J)Z (light greylist, reflection)
> E/ANR_LOG: >>> msg's executing time is too long
> E/ANR_LOG: Blocked msg = { when=-3s60ms what=110 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H
> obj=AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{a9c47f1 com.example.together}}
> } , cost  = 2918 ms
> E/ANR_LOG: >>>Current msg List is:
> E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <1>  = { when=-3s51ms what=159 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ClientTransaction hashCode,
> mActivityToken = android.os.BinderProxy@7dc3fd6 }
> E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <2>  = { when=-2s369ms what=149 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.os.BinderProxy@7dc3fd6
> }
> E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <3>  = { when=+9s993ms what=132 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H }
> E/ANR_LOG: >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
> I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
> (light greylist, reflection)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light
> greylist, reflection)
> D/MMListParser: +++initMMListConfigFile gInitDone 0
> D/MMListParser: onlineVersion -1 defaultVersion 20191107
> D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
> I/SurfaceFactory: [static] sSurfaceFactory = com.mediatek.view.impl.SurfaceFactoryImpl@e828b0d
> D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: DecorView@cc70410[MainActivity], this =
> android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@859cb09, pkg = com.example.together
> D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false,
> forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
> I/InputTransport: Create ARC handle: 0x7d64903200
> V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@c0e610e, this = DecorView@cc70410[MainActivity]
> D/libARC: etEventThreadFunc()::thread Begin. eventRefCnt: 1
> I/Choreographer: Skipped 2 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
> D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7d6490a000)
> D/libEGL: ARC_TRACE: arc_initARCTraceLevel
> D/libEGL: Active EGL Table is EglArcHook
> I/Choreographer: Skipped 5 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
> E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
> I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay
> retrieved: 0
> I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay
> retrieved: 0
> I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
> D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
> D/libEGL: [GIFT] clean GIFT bit (0)
> I/libARC: gli_eglCreateContextRet() tid:23800, ctx: 0x7d703b5880, ARC not Enabled.
> D/libEGL: ARC_TRACE: ARC_eglCreateContext() => ctx: 0x7d703b5880
> D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7d6490a000,api=1)
> E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
> E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (light
> greylist, reflection)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceEnd(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (light
> greylist, reflection)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceCounter(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (light
> greylist, reflection)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->()V (light greylist, reflection)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z
> (light greylist, reflection)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z
> (light greylist, reflection)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (light greylist, reflection)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (light greylist,
> reflection)
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: start
> W/xample.togethe: constructJavaHashMap: end
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: start
> W/xample.togethe: sendCommonDcs: end
> W/xample.togethe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface;
> (light greylist, reflection)
> W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@69f872
> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.together, PID: 23620
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.together/com.example.together.login}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML
> file line #26: Error inflating class 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3201)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3338)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2029)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7212)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class 
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class 
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
> at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:730)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:813)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:890)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:851)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
> at com.example.together.login.onCreate(login.java:34)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7376)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7367)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3181)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3338)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2029)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7212)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable
> com.example.together:drawable/inner_layout with resource ID
> #0x7f080095
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
> res/drawable/inner_layout.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080095
> at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1001)
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:764)
> at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:943)
> at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:955)
> at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
> at android.view.View.(View.java:5090)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:670)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:244)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:240)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:236)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.together/com.example.together.login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class`

`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/inner_layout.xml`

looks like your `inner_layout.xml` is placed in some `drawable-...` folder (density bucket), which may be unavailable on devices with different screen params (not related to Android version at all). this file probably should be placed in `drawable` folder (without `-...` suffix)

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful :) good luck!